# Heroku Not Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have been learning Ruby on Rails with heroku from an online tutorial. Everything has been working fine. However, my latest attempt to update my heroku site has failed.

i've run:

"git push heroku master"
and
"heroku run rake db:migrate"

however, my local changes are not updating.

note: the only changes that don't seem to be taking affect are database updates. for instance, i can update the home file and see its changes on heroku, but i can't login to a new user account with devise.

Comment: Did you make a git commit before pushing

Comment: yes. i did run a "git commit" first.

Comment: Can you post any errors from your terminal for what `git push heroku master` is showing, as well as `heroku logs` is showing.

Comment: Are you trying to push css and other information? Have you precompiled your assets. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: Hunters-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting hunter$ git push heroku master
Everything up-to-date --->

"heroku logs":
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/13b377bbdab6284c801e

Comment: What behavior are you seeing on the site.  Is it working and just not updating?  You can also try "heroku restart" which will restart the dynos.   I would do as Marc suggested: 1) run "Heroku rur heroku logs --tail", then do git push heroku  master(or whatever your branch is named) and post the output.

Comment: the project does utilize css, but i have not made any changes as of late. i'm not sure if i have precompiled the assets.

Comment: already tried "heroku restart" the site is working it just is not updating, my changes since the last heroku push are not showing. for instance, i created a user accounts with devise, and it is telling me that the account does not exist.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing on the site. Is it working and just not updating?

Comment: not updating since changes of last push.

Comment: okay. i tried just editing the html of the home page. it updated. however, i am unable to login to a user account. so something is wrong with the database update?

Comment: Have you run your migrations? `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: i've run heroku rake db:migrate numerous times. should i try just creating a new heroku and upload everything fresh? how would i do that?

Comment: @Hunter Run git status and post results please.